# How can you change all appearances of a text response in Karate DSL without having a placeholder?

Tags: json, api, http, testing, karate

I am wondering if it is possible to change all occurrences of a text in a Json response from a Karate DSL text without having a placeholder. For example , the fragment "https://thisisthepart.tochange" appears many times in the json response of karate dsl. I cannot do it with "set" because i do not know for which keys is going to appear that text.

"imageUrl": ["https://thisisthepart.tochange/idontwannachange/thispart"]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, convert to a string, use the Java API `String.replace()` and re-convert:

```
* string response = response
* json response = response.replace('foo', 'bar')
```

Also refer: https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion

EDIT: note that you can "re-build" JSON using a loop:

```
* def before = { a: 'hello', b: 'world' }
* def after = {}
* def fun = function(k, v){ after[k] = v + 'edit' }
* karate.forEach(before, fun)
* match after == { a: 'helloedit', b: 'worldedit' }
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. The problem is that after converting it again to a Json , all "/" characters in the whole json object  seem to be converted to "\ /" as if it were escaped or so ....

Comment: @Ramon no idea. you can try using different search patterns and being aware of how the Java `String.replace()` works. maybe you should try looping over all key-values and re-build a JSON using `karate.forEach()` - see my edit

Comment: will try that. Thank you